# Expanding dhcp range on DC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I work for a relatively small company and we are starting to run out of ip addresses for our DHCP server. We currently have a scope of 192.168.10.0/24. This was all set up by an IT company 3 years before I was hired. I am looking for the best practice in expanding our ip range while keeping the network config the same for our static ips (printers, voip system, ect).

I started as a help desk agent and am now taking on the position of Network Admin but lack the experience. Any suggestions or comments will be welcomed.

Our network servers consist of a DC, File server, application server, and terminal server. We also have a UNIFI switch with multiple APs.

Comment: You'll change to --> **192.168.10.0 /23** 
Range: **192.168.10.0 - 192.168.11.255**                                                 IP Addresses: **512**
Mask: **255.255.254.0**. You'll likely want to look up and research **Resubnetting DHCP** with your version of DHCP for your Windows Server DHCP IP, and assuming that 512 IP addresses will suffice for the new need. If you have routers and any other network routing devices, you'll probably need to expand or check those configs as well to ensure traffic will be allowed throughout the entire network.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a new IP range, for example 192.168.12.0/23. You could then put desktop computers and laptops there and keep server and printers in the old range. DHCP would be strictly used in the new range.